# How Can I run this program by using "for" loops

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I have made a program that prompts the user to enter two numbers. If those numbers are even multiples I will diplay all the odd numbers between the two numbers. If those numbers are not even multiples I will ask the user to re enter the two numbers. I have made this program successfully using while loops. But I want to know how I could make a program like this using "for" loops instead. Here is my original code which is where I use while loops. All tips and advice would help.

```
/**
 * Description: This program takes two integers entered by the user and 
 * displays the odd numbers between the integers if the integers entered
 * are even multiples. If the integers entered are not even multiples,
 * the program will prompt the user to re enter the integers.
 */

/**
 * This is the main loops class. This class
 * includes the main method as well
 * as the program method.
 */

public class loops { 

/**
 * This is the main method. It provides an 
 * entry into the program.
 */
  public static void main (String []args) {

    loops lps = new loops();//Instantiating loops class.
    lps.program();//Invoking the program method on the loops class. 

  }


/**
 * This is the program method. This
 * method will carry out the program
 * functions.
 */
  public void program() {

/**
 * Declaring variables that
 * will be used in the program.
 */
    int firstNumber;
    int secondNumber;   
    int finalNumber;

    java.util.Scanner input=new java.util.Scanner(System.in);//Using the Java utility scanner.

    try {//Try statement. Used to handle exceptions.
    do {//Using a do-while loop.

/**
 * Prompting the user to enter two
 * integers. Then taking the remainder
 * of the integers.
 */
      System.out.println("Enter your first number."); 
      firstNumber = input.nextInt();
      input.nextLine();

      System.out.println("Enter your second number."); 
      secondNumber = input.nextInt();

      finalNumber = firstNumber % secondNumber;

      if(finalNumber !=0) {//If the remainder is not zero, these statements should be printed.
        System.out.println("Please enter even multiples.");     
      System.out.println("(Try switching the order in which you input the numbers)");
      } 
    }

/**
 * This is a while loop that will keep prompting the
 * user to enter two integers until the remainder
 * of the two integers is 0 and the two numbers
 * entered are even multiples.
 */
    while (finalNumber !=0);

    if(finalNumber == 0) {//The following code will be executed only if the remainder is 0.

      System.out.println("Displaying all odd numbers between " + firstNumber + " and " + secondNumber);

      int number = secondNumber;//Declaring number variable, giving it value of secondNumber.

/**
 * This is a while loop that will display all the odd
 * numbers between the two integers entered. 
 */
      while(number <= firstNumber){
        if (number % 2 != 0) {
          System.out.println(number);
        }
        number++;
      }
    }
    }

    catch (java.util.InputMismatchException e) { //Catching multiple exceptions.
     System.out.println("Please enter whole numbers.");
    }

    catch ( java.lang.ArithmeticException e) { //Catching multiple exceptions.
     System.out.println("Please enter whole numbers.");
    }


  } 
}
```

Comment: When you say "This is a while loop that will keep prompting the user..." you know that isn't a separate loop, right? It's the last part of the do/while loop above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where you do this:

```
while (finalNumber !=0)
```

you can do this:

```
for (;finalNumber != 0;)
```

(putting the condition at the start of the loop, of course, since `for` doesn't have a `do... while` equivalent)  And where you do this:

```
while(number <= firstNumber)
```

you can do this:

```
for (;number <= firstNumber;)
```

or you can combine some of the statements and move two lines of code into the loop condition:

```
for (int number = secondNumber; number <= firstNumber; number++)
```

Whether or not that makes the code meaningfully cleaner or more expressive is a matter of opinion, of course.  It's not clear why you want to replace `while` with `for`, but in any event the structure of loops is the same.  `for` just has syntax for two more statements in the loop condition, one to start the loop and one to increment the loop.  The terminating condition is exactly the same.

---

Side note, this if condition is superfluous:

```
// ...
while (finalNumber !=0);
if(finalNumber == 0)
// ...
```

By definition, when that `if` condition is reached, `finalNumber` *must* be `0`.  The immediate previous line already tested that condition.  You don't need to test the same condition twice, the runtime isn't going to lie about the value of `finalNumber` :)